# com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I want to make Google maps to use in Android, but I have some problems.

[Screenshot](https://plus.google.com/photos/108223064698406147078/albums/5924548382675899265/5924548387362118466?pid=5924548387362118466&oid=108223064698406147078)

**Manifest:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.odv"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
 android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="your.package.name.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission  android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />


    <!-- Maps API needs OpenGL ES 2.0. -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <!-- You must insert your own Google Maps for Android API v2 key in here. -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyCe29ye5iK83zx6rUBnCzulKCxf68nT-bs" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.odv.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**main XML:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
     Copyright (C) 2012 The Android Open Source Project

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- This can go anywhere in your layout (see other demos for some examples). 
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
-->
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

**Mainactivity:**

```
    package com.example.odv;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity  {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

I want to learn Android.  I think I have algorithmic intelligence for programming, but I don't know how I can start to learn programming.  I don't have a good source.

I wrote this code, but I can't see maps.  I can only see a white screen and can't open maps.  What can I do for this?

Screenshot

Comment: that permission is not longer needed

Comment: I think you'll want to edit this question for clarity, as the English really isn't the only thing that's bad here — it's a code dump, there's no research shown, no problem explanation, etc. (i.e., What is the actual problem here? Is there a compiler error? An exception?) After that, other folks will probably be able to come in and fix your grammar / spelling and so on.

Comment: refer this one for map http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/showing-current-location-using-onmylocationchangelistener-in-google-map-android-api-v2/

Comment: Do'nt give any error 
only open and screen shoow white maps(you cant see maps,white screen)

https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=1409820722568584&set=a.1409817935902196.1073741829.100006220094521&type=1&relevant_count=1&ref=nf

Comment: It seems like a wrong key error. Have you added your debugkey signature to the API console?

Comment: yes Ido it 4 times but always the same (whit screen you can see in pics

Comment: Tanks your :) 
I am try

Answer (score 0):

The very first thing you need to do is, get the API key from [API CONSOLE](https://code.google.com/apis/console/b/0/#project:429754612951) and then you need to use that api key in your Android Manifest:
1st Use proper permissions:

Second: Use Feature

```
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" >
```

Third:
 In the meta data:

android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
   android:value="Your key goes here" >

Hope this helps..:)

Comment: The permissions are <permission
        android:name="com.mike.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

and in the uses-permission:
 <uses-permission android:name="com.mike.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

Answer (score 0):

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

```
private static final int GPS_ERRORDIALOG_REQUEST = 9001;
Button btn1;
EditText et1;
EditText et2;

GoogleMap map;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (servicesOK()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Ready to map!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        setContentView(R.layout.testmap);

    } else {
        setContentView(R.layout.activitymain);

    }

    /*
     * et1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext1); et2 =
     * (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext2); btn1 =
     * (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
     * 
     * btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
     */

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

/*
 * @Override public void onClick(View v) {
 * 
 * Object lat = et1; Object lon = et2;
 * 
 * Uri uri=Uri.parse("geo:"+lat.toString()+","+lon.toString()); Intent i=new
 * Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri); startActivity(i); Log.d("The Location:",
 * lat.toString()+lon.toString());
 * 
 * 
 * }
 */
public boolean servicesOK() {

    int isAvailable = GooglePlayServicesUtil
            .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

    if (isAvailable == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {

        return true;

    } else if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(isAvailable)) {

        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(isAvailable,
                this, GPS_ERRORDIALOG_REQUEST);
        dialog.show();

    } else {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Cant connect!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Also, I just a mapview in the layout and please don't forget to put the API KEY in the manifest because without that, the map won't load. And to use map, please use a real device and not the emulator..:)

Comment: This is the layout:

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    
    xmlns:maps="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

Comment: I use the my phone :(

Comment: ...
         SHA1: 12:4A:F6:FE:9A:F6:2D:26:91:72:B1:3E:3B:34:A3:DF:A9:6F:13:30
         SHA256: 0C:78:D5:AD:5B:54:70:43:1B:6B:AB:96:8B:0B:04:57:74:E6:B3:78:B3:
3E:2C:2D:61:49:6E:A2:53:62:99:DF
         Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
         Version: 3

Extensions:

#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 69 88 12 01 60 76 8D 41   64 72 AB 05 CE 19 BF 31  i...`v.Adr.....1
0010: B8 BB 1E 61                                        ...a
]
]
I use Sha1 for key and (Criticality=false ) is normal ?

Comment: Tanks your :) 
I am try

Comment: I know but I am trying to better :)

Comment: hi mike20132013
"Ready to map!!  Say it and
[2013-09-18 18:02:34 - odv] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.odv/.MainActivity }
[2013-09-18 18:02:34 - odv] ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front 
_____
what do you think about it

Answer (score 0):

Here's the complete working of the maps I used in my test app:

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

```
private static final int GPS_ERRORDIALOG_REQUEST = 9001;
Button btn1;
EditText et1;
EditText et2;

GoogleMap map;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (servicesOK()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Ready to map!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        setContentView(R.layout.testmap);

    } else {
        setContentView(R.layout.activitymain);

    }

    /*
     * et1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext1); et2 =
     * (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext2); btn1 =
     * (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
     * 
     * btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
     */

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

/*
 * @Override public void onClick(View v) {
 * 
 * Object lat = et1; Object lon = et2;
 * 
 * Uri uri=Uri.parse("geo:"+lat.toString()+","+lon.toString()); Intent i=new
 * Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri); startActivity(i); Log.d("The Location:",
 * lat.toString()+lon.toString());
 * 
 * 
 * }
 */
public boolean servicesOK() {

    int isAvailable = GooglePlayServicesUtil
            .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

    if (isAvailable == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {

        return true;

    } else if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(isAvailable)) {

        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(isAvailable,
                this, GPS_ERRORDIALOG_REQUEST);
        dialog.show();

    } else {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Cant connect!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    return false;
}
```

}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Here's the layout:

```
xmlns:maps="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Here's the Android Manifest:

```
package="com.mike.maps"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<permission
    android:name="com.mike.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.mike.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" >
</uses-feature>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.mike.maps.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.mike.maps.SecondActivity" >
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="Your key goes here" >
    </meta-data>
</application>
```

Comment: dont open map in phone and target :(
can you send me full file in zip  Please
email huseyin730@gmail.com 
Play never ever used it on google.
and I did not pay google playa
so Could it be  key error